# iOS app compatibility issue

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility, armv7

I'm making an application with Swift 2.1, Xcode 7.1.1.
I want it to be at least compatible with iPhone 4S and 5C.

I configured my project settings with armv7 architecture, info.plist, but when I publish my build, I only have arm64 defined in iTunes connect.

[image: See screenshots here]

Where do I have to configure it correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure *Build Active Architecture Only* is set to **NO** (at least for release), or else it will use the architecture of the connected device at the time you create the build.

[image]

Comment: note: only enable it for debug! there it is fine but it shouldn't be enabled for release

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed this parameter ! It solved the problem, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

please remove

> `<string>armv7</string>`

from the array in

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

in info.plist

and submit the app for review on iTunes Connect.